# Find the number of paths that run through an edge between two vertex

Tags: algorithm, graph, topological-sort

I have an algorithm to determine, in a DAG, the number of paths from each vertex to a specific vertex **t** (which has out-degree equal to 0). Now I choose other specific vertex **s** with 0 in-degree. I have to develop another algorithm to determine, for each edge **(u, v)**, the number of paths that run through **(u, v)** from **s** to **t** in O(|V|+|E|).

I have tried to modify the BFS (since with a DFS I think is impossible to reach the solution) but if I have an edge with more than one paths, it doesn't work. Could you suggest me or give me a hint about how can I focus my work to get the solution?

By the way, the problem is related to topological sort.

Thanks so much in advance! :)

Comment: Yes, the problem is related to topological sort. You can use any order a topological sort produces to calculate what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You already have an answer from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18087559/572670) to find number of paths from all vertices to a target node `t`.

So, in specific, using this algorithm,  you have #paths from `v` to `t`. 

Using this algorithm, you can also find paths from `s` to `u`.

**The total number of paths from `s` to `t` that uses `(u,v)` is exactly `#paths(s,u) * #paths(v,t)`**

---

**Explanation:**

Number of paths from `s` to `u` is given from correctness of algorithm. You have exactly one choice to go forward to `v`, thus number of paths from `s` to `v` is also the same number. Now, you can continue from `v` to `t` using each of the `#paths(v,t)`, giving you total of `#paths(s,u)*#paths(v,t)`

**Complexity:**

The algorithm requries to find twice number of paths from node a to node b, each is `O(V+E)`, so the complexity of this algorithm is also `O(V+E)`

---

Attachment: algorithm to find #paths from all vertices to a target node `t`:

```
Topological sort the vertices, let the ordered vertices be v1,v2,...,vn
create new array of size t, let it be arr
init: arr[t] = 1
for i from t-1 to 1 (descending, inclusive):
    arr[i] = 0  
    for each edge (v_i,v_j) such that i < j <= t:
         arr[i] += arr[j]
```

Proof and analysis in the original question (linked).

Comment: But I have to use the result of the previous algorithm to solve this one. It's like I already have, in the vertex data structure, the number of paths to t.