# Find The Number Of Paths From u To v In Graph Using Dynamic Programming

Tags: graph, dynamic-programming, topological-sort

Given a directed acyclic graph, how can I find the number of paths from vertex u to vertex v in using a dynamic programming algorithm that runs in linear time(if possible, through also using topological sorting)?

Comment: Found an answer for the question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087559/topological-sort-to-find-the-number-of-paths-to-t?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Topological sort to find the number of paths to t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087559/topological-sort-to-find-the-number-of-paths-to-t)

Comment: Check this link [All_Paths_In_A_DAG](https://www.algotree.org/algorithms/tree_graph_traversal/depth_first_search/all_paths_in_a_graph/)
The method described in this link uses a simple DFS  with backtracking to find all paths in a directed acyclic graph.